# How to get a unevaluted expression from a compressed string?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, hold

Of course we know

```
Defer[Range[20]]
```

> `Range[20]`

But I try to compress my expression into a string

```
com = Compress;
SetAttributes[com, HoldAllComplete]
string = com[Range[10]]
```

> `1:eJxTTMoPSuNiYGAoZgESPpnFJZ6MQIYhmDQCk8Zg0gRMmoJJMzBpDiYtwKSlJxNIlwEApm8I6w==`

I cannot get a unevaluted expression from it?

```
Defer /@ Uncompress[string]
```

> `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`

Actually the `Range[20]` is the expected output.How to do this?

Comment: Anyone can add a appropriate tag for this question?I cannot think out of it..

Comment: Try this: `myCompress = Function[x, Compress[Unevaluated[x]], HoldAll]; test = cc[Range[10]]; Uncompress[test, Defer]`.

Comment: @J.M. Your comment always is a good answer. :)

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for warmth,but it deserve `function-construction`?

Comment: I think your question fits the description of the tag. (In my eyes, your question is "why doesn't my function `com` work?" ) Feel free to remove it if you think it's improper. BTW if you're not interested in defining a function for the task, simply use `Compress@Unevaluated@Range[20]`.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to wrap the expression `Unevaluated` before passing it to `Compress`, which means defining your own function instead of just assigning `Compress` to `com`:

```
ClearAll[com];

SetAttributes[com, HoldAllComplete]; 
com[expr_] := Compress[Unevaluated[expr]];

string = com[Range[10]] 
(* "1:eJxTTMoPSmNkYGAoZgUSQYl56amZXEAWADzBBIQ=" *)
```

And then make sure to wrap it in `Hold` or `Defer` when you pull it back out, which you can do with the second argument of `Uncompress`:

```
Uncompress[string, Defer]    
(* Range[10] *)
```

Comment: Ah, we were thinking the same thing... +1!

Comment: Good lesson,thanks..